# Why does my query return null when subquery condition is false

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have these three tables in my Firebird database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_CODE_MASTER 
( 
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    CLIENT_CODE VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    CLIENT_ACTIVE BOOLEAN, 
    MAX_DD_LIMIT DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    DEALER_LOGIN_ID VARCHAR(50),
    DEALER_NAME VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE TRADE_DATE_MASTER 
( 
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , 
    TRADE_DATE DATE UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE FUTURES_DAILY_CLIENT_MTM 
(
    TRADE_DATE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES TRADE_DATE_MASTER(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CLIENT_CODE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES CLIENT_CODE_MASTER(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    TURNOVER DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    MTOM DECIMAL(20,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TRADE_DATE_ID, CLIENT_CODE_ID)
);
```

Now when running this query:

```sql
select 
    (select client_code from client_code_master ccm 
     where ccm.id = client_code_id and ccm.client_active = true) as client_code,
    (select trade_date from trade_date_master 
     where id = trade_date_id) as trade_date
from 
    futures_daily_client_mtm;
```

The column 'client_code' is showing [null] where the condition `ccm.client_active = true` is not satisfied.

[image: Query result]

These rows should not be in the result.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: You have no WHERE clause in your main query so no rows is filtered. Use JOIN instead of subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a singleton select like that as an expression in the column list of another select, it will produce `NULL` when that singleton select produces no row. Your select statement basically says, for each row produced by the `from`, execute two other queries and show their result. The fact one of those queries produced no result doesn't mean it should suddenly exclude that row, instead it will display `NULL` in that column.

If you want to excluded rows where the result of the subquery is `NULL`, you need to explicitly exclude it (e.g. by making it a derived table, and then excluding rows by using `where client_code is not null`), but better, as user13964273 mentioned in the comments, is to solve this by using an `INNER JOIN` instead:

```sql
select ccm.client_code, tdm.trade_date
from futures_daily_client_mtm fdcm
inner join client_code_master ccm 
  on ccm.id = fdcm.client_code_id and ccm.client_active = true
inner join trade_date_master tdm 
  on tdm.id = fdcm.trade_date_id
```